# No original data sources Tableau twbx

Tags: tableau-api

Hi every one i m newbie to the tableau i have question regarding usability of tableau twbx files for practice after unpacking in the data folder i didn't find any original excel files/original data sources to load again for practice in case of practice how to practice without original files,i found twb and extracts with calculation fields how to use these files for practice  please some one suggest me how to practice from twbx files without excel files.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand the question.  What is it that you want to practice?

Comment: yes,i want to practice from twbx files but i am unable to find the data source after unpacking twbx files

Comment: Which version of Tableau are you using? If you install Tableau Reader, can you still open the .twbx file and see the views without error?

Comment: i am using latest version 10.1 my concern is how do i practice without original excel source which was built earlier twbx files ,simply once after unpacking twbx files how should i practice with extract(.tde version) or twb files if i didnt find original excel data files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, for whatever reason, a packaged workbook does not contain the original underlying datasources (be those flat files or a .tde extract), you can [replace the missing datasource with an equivalent datasource that has the same data structure](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v10.1/pro/desktop/en-us/connect_basic_replace.html).

If you are unable to replace the datasource, then it is still possible to open the workbook and see the structure of the view (which dimensions and measures are in use) but no data will be displayed.

If you simply want to practice, and you have valid maintenance, I suggest installing the latest version (2018.1) and then download interesting workbooks from Tableau Public or simply just play around with the sample workbooks that come with Tableau Desktop.